# Capture/getting PopUp/Message Box Contents using VBA/VBS/PowerShell

Tags: powershell, vbscript

Had automated a process and in between will be getting a Windows popup based on the success or failure of the process. Now we want to capture the body of the message box which will be displayed intermediately.

Can any one help me on this? I'm allowed to use any of the below languages:

- VBA
- VBScript
- PowerShell

We want to capture the text "There is no password on the Admin user".

[image: message box screenshot]

Comment: I sense an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). What is that "process" you have automated? How is it automated? How is it invoked? Does it return a status code?

Comment: I have an automated process. mean while i need to look at this window to make sure that the process is a success or not.

Comment: If you think that would clarify anything: it doesn't.